# Would reporting a violating comment beneficial if it has a rule reminder?

Tags: moderators, rules-and-policies, comments, reddit

In the subreddit Change My View, a person give a response why my view wouldn't work. I give a response to them, and this is how it goes:

> - *Yeah, this only supports everything I said before*
>   - can you explain more?
>   - *No, probably not - you seem to have difficulty seeing the situation objectively*
>   - I understand that challenging any view is hard, but because I have difficulty seeing the situation objectively, and you have it, so that's why I ask on this sub. Simple refutation violates rule 5 I'm afraid.
>   - *Fair enough - if you report me, the mods will deal with it.*

My question are:

- Is let it be beneficial to me? Maybe the reminder can entice others to form a constructive response?
- Is not reporting beneficial to the sub? There is no rule forcing me to report it, but it is highly encouraged to do so.
- Is this the best way to entice this user to restore? I'm still curious to know why this person sees my refutation actually supports theirs.

If there are two much questions, then I have more interest in the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is 'let it be' beneficial to me? Maybe the reminder can entice others to form a constructive response?

That's something we can't answer for you, nor can we predict the actions and opinions of others.

People might know they don't want to offer responses like the other person did, or they may see it as an invitation.

> Is not reporting beneficial to the sub? There is no rule forcing me to report it, but it is highly encouraged to do so.

See first answer and the remainder.

> Is this the best way to entice this user to restore? I'm still curious to know why this person sees my refutation actually supports theirs.

Without a link to the thread we can't see the context. I searched for the words on the forum and checked recent posts; nothing came up.

I can only guess that they are implying that "Since you don't understand, that supports their position that you don't understand".

Report and move on.

The other choice is to demand a full explanation to your complete satisfaction, sometimes people do that on our sites; it's usually not well received and eventually leads to a 'Moved to Chat' message, sometimes a scolding.

Reddit has looser rules than here and that sub encourages arguing - not sure that a flag will be acted upon without something much ruder - and very difficult for **us** to second guess without a link to the thread.